# Unity WebGL HTTP Request without IEnumerator or Coroutine

Tags: http, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

As the title tells I'm trying to make a HTTP Request in Unity (WebGL).

In the documentation I found here: [WebGL Networking](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html) they tell me to create a `IEnumerator` type function and call it via a `StartCoroutine` call.

This is all fine, my problem is that I need to provide a callback `HttpRequest` to a class that is in another library.

My callback looks like this:

```cs
private string HttpRequest(string url, string method, string body=null) {

    WWW www = null; // = null is compiler candy

    if (method == "GET") {
        www = new WWW(url);
    } else if (method == "POST") {
        //POST specific implementation...
    } else {
       // do something else
    }

    while (!www.isDone) { } // this is Wrong.
    return www.text;
}
```

The problem is that unless I return from `HttpRequest` and the calling method JavaScript won't be able to handle the request. But on the other hand the calling method expects a `string` not some kind of `IEnumerator`.

Is there some workaround to let JavaScript do it's work after the WWW class has been constructed?

Comment: I didn't fully understand what speaks against the `IEnumerator`?

Comment: `IEnumerator` is nice, the problem is that the library which calls my HttpRequest callback expects Synchronously the http response as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

`WWW` and `UnityWebRequest` are asynchronous.

To do a synchronous request you need write a javascript plugin. By using some library it's not very complicated, such as jquery.

```js
function getdata($url, $method, $data)
{
    var text = '';

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: $method,
        async: false, //synchronous request
        data: $data,
        success: function(data){
            text = data;
        },
        error: function(data){
            text = data;
        }
    });

    return text;
}
```

More information:

[Communication between javascript and unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

[jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: How could I call this jQuery code from inside a Unity function? In other words can I call a JavaScript function from Unity?

Comment: Use `DllImportAttribute` in your unity code. Please take a look at the first link.

Comment: Sorry I answered to fast, I'll try out if I can write my callback as a bridge to js.

Comment: Can I include jQuery code inside a .jslib method? can I run this methods in the Unity editor?

Comment: Usually you don't need include it, add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in head scope of index.html. The method can't run in editor.